# How to group a text row in multiple data rows in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

Basically I'd like to from this :
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBlPM.png)

To this :
[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFVEB.png)

Case in Orange are data that I pick up with an sql request while "This e-learning phase..." is just a plain text.
Does anybody knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Parent Row Group and Group by the Information field.

Unfortunately, this would place the Information on the Left side of the table. Fortunately, there is a Layout Direction property for the table that can be switched from `LTR` to `RTL` so that the table is created from Right to Left instead of the default Left to Right.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This way the grouped information field on the right would only have one cell while there may be multiple Activities.

Comment: Nice! I never thought of switch the layout direction...

Comment: Thank you ! I was able after some fidgeting to do what I wanted !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do this exactly how you want. This is because you cannot add rowgroup columns after non-grouped columns.

The only way you could get close is to not show the text if it's not the first row in the dataset (or rowgroup if the report is grouped somewhere)

You could use something like this in the `Value` expression.

```
=IIF(
    ROWNUMBER("myDataSet_Namehere") =1,
    "This e-learning phase must be completed before the start of the classroom part indicated below.",
    Nothing
    )
```

You could use a similar check to then set the vertical alignment property.

It looks like this...

[image]

The other option would be to move the test to the top of the table on it's own row in above the column headers, it would probably look neater..

Or you can wait for somebody else to come up with a better solution :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I really want it on one row